# Check for powerstate of server every 15 min powershell

Tags: powershell

I am installing OS and need to execute a report once the server comes on **powered on** state

I am trying the below code but it is not coming out of the loop and keep sending the report

```
if($getvm.PowerState -eq "PoweredOn") {
    while ($true) {
    
        $result = @()

        $servername = $getvm.Name
        $osversion = $getvm.ExtensionData.Guest.GuestFullName
        $vmhost = $getvm.VMHost.Name
        $vmdatacenter = $vmhost.Substring(0, 4).ToUpper() 

        $datacenter = Get-Datacenter -VM $getvm | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
        $Cluster = get-cluster -VM $getvm | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
        $vmtoolversion = $getvm | Select-Object -Property @{Name='ToolsVersion';Expression={$_.Guest.ToolsVersion}}
        $vCPU = [int]$getvm.NumCpu
        $RAM = [int]$getvm.MemoryGB
        $vmnetwork = (Get-NetworkAdapter $getvm).Name
        $networkNames = [string]::Join(';', $vmnetwork)

        $details = [pscustomobject]@{            
            ServerName       = $servername;              
            'OS Version'     = $osversion;                 
            DataCenter       = $vmdatacenter;
            Cluster          = $Cluster;
            vCPU             = $vCPU;
            RAM              = $RAM;
            Network          = $networkNames
        } 

        $csvData = $details | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | 
            ForEach-Object {
                [pscustomobject] @{Name=$_.name;Value=$details.($_.Name)}
            } | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

        $csvData | Set-Content -Path $postcheckreportame.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append

        $fromEmail = ""
        $smtpServer = ""
        $toEmail = ""
        $toCCmail1 = ""

        $body = @"

<html>

Hi Team, <br /><br />

***This is an auto-generated email. Please do not respond***

</html>

"@


        #Send-MailMessage -from $fromEmail -to $toEmail -Cc $toCCmail1 -SmtpServer $smtpServer -Body $body -Subject "PostCheck report for $servername"        
    }
    # Wait for $interval minutes before checking the server uptime again
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $interval
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here. if the VM is **PoweredOn** then it should send the report and go to next step else it should wait for 15 min and again check the state

Comment: Your while loop's condition is `true`, so it will always loop.  You have an `if` condition before that; but that controls whether or not the code gets to the `while` statement.  Get rid of your `if` statement and move your conditional logic to the `while`'s condition.  You may also need to update `$getvm` so it gets a new value for `poweredOn`... depends if that's just a variable, or if there's a script behind that property dynamically updating its value.

Comment: @JohnLBevan: Thanks for your response. `$getvm` is having the value of vm powerstate which I am getting from vcenter.

Comment: But what happens if the value changes; i.e. when you fetch the value it's `PoweredOn`... if 30 mins later the VM is powered off, how does the value of `$getvm.PowerState` know / how is that value updated?